# MOSHI json - Automatic convertion of property names to/from snake case

Tags: android, moshi

Is there any way to automatically apply naming conventions to Moshi when serializing data using Moshi?

e.g.

I have this class which follows Kotlin naming conventions for properties (camel case)

```
class Player {
    var currentHealth: Int = 100
    var firstName = "John"
    var lastName = "Doe"
}
```

I would like to serialize it to something which will stick to the naming conventions we have on the server (snake case):

```
{ 
    current_health: 100,
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe"
}
```

**I already know we can customize column names on each property manually. Just looking for a way to do that automatically (for instance if we add properties to the POJO or on server side).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the Moshi developers and it doesn't have this feature because I think it is harmful. I've described why in full detail [here](https://publicobject.com/2016/01/20/strict-naming-conventions-are-a-liability/). In brief, case mapping breaks your ability to search across your codebase.

Comment: Honestly, I have read your blog and I do not agree. In the end, what you do here is add more code to write for every data model. I have been using Gson for 4 years in commercial projects, the REST Api changed all the time, and I did update data models, remove fields, resolve problems with backend developers etc. No problem. What Moshi does is (as you state in your blog) it "adds unnecessary complexity to your program". Please do not force this corner-case ideology on the developers. People have brains, and can switch cases when searching.

Comment: You don't need to write more code; you can use snake_case or whatever in the field name.

Comment: Which forces underscores in frontend code, which is a code smell (and look plain ugly tbh: `label.text = model.some_raw_field_with_text`)

Comment: Eh, you should consider embracing ugly, smelly code. I’ve found it’s actually quite handy to have a big obvious signal that a field is used by JSON. It warns me that renaming or refactoring fields could break JSON!

Comment: FWIW from an outside perspective as an iOS developer, I really appreciate Apple's [approach to converting from snake case](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase). It also allows individual explicit overrides for the times when you need to break convention. After numerous years using this strategy, and dealing with many API changes, it's never bitten me.

Comment: I am surprised and puzzled by your response. When I hear something like that from a talented dev I die a little inside. When you say "rebel against the system" what system do you have in mind? Coding conventions? It is like saying "let's rebel agains punctuation". Moreover in your blog you just gave a lot of opinion based reasons. No proof whatsoever but even if there was some, everyone's situation is different. Code conventions exist for a reason - simplify coding. If you break them, you just create more work for others. Now you have to work with trivialities. I would NOT call that smart.